# Write data to an external USB storage with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

After careful research on the internet I found the method to display an external USB in the Files app. The problem I’m now experiencing is how to access it directly (or through selection) from my App.

My need is to write and store a file inside the external storage, does anyone know any method with Swift or Objective-C?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**: After some tests I have momentarily resolved saving the file in a temporary folder and moving it later through the preview of the Document Interaction Controller. However, I find this solution not ideal in terms of the UX experience.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

Comment: It says that I don't have permissions to save the file in the external storage. Some tips? Thanks for the response.

Comment: Do you have the `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` in your Info.plist file?